# compute the derivative of the function F(t)

Tags: calculus

$$F(t)=\iint {e}^{\frac{tx}{y}}dxdy$$
where $$0.1\le{x}\le{t}$$and$$0.1\le{y}\le{t}$$
Please help me to find$${F}'(t)$$

I tried the antiderivatives. But $F(t)$ doesn't seem to be an elementary integral.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{0.1}^t{{\rm e}^{{\frac {xt}{y}}}}{dx}=\frac{y}{t}\left(e^\frac{t^2}{y}-e^{0.1\frac{t}{y}}\right)$$

$\int\frac{y}{t}e^{\frac{t^2}{y}}dy$ and $\int\frac{y}{t}e^{0.1\frac{t}{y}}dy$ are nonelementary integrals.

MAPLE gave the following result.

$$\frac{1}{200t^2}(-300Ei_1(-10t^2)t^4+(-30t^2+1)e^{10t^2}+(300t^4+t^2)Ei_1(-t)-Ei_1(-\frac{1}{10})t^2-110t^2e^{\frac{1}{10}}+300e^t(t^3+\frac{1}{3}t^2+\frac{1}{300}t-\frac{1}{300}))$$